# Write a jump command to a x86-64 binary file

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, patch

I'm debugging a Mac OS X 64bit app with GDB. I see that jumping over a chunk of code solves all my problems.

But:

How can I patch the executable file to implement the jump? I want the app to automatically jump to a defined point in the code without the debugger.

This is what I want to do:

At address `0x1000027a9` (given by the debugger) jump to address `0x100003b6e`.
I'm trying very hard to do it via HexEdit, but with no success. I read anywhere about jmp to absolute addresses opcodes (`FF` seems the right opcode, but it's a call, not a jump...) but nothing works. Bad access, segfault.

How can I do that?

Comment: The usual ways of doing this are: 1) fix the code & rebuild, 2) file a bug with the app vendor. Why are you trying to patch this yourself?

Comment: You need something like this when you have a very old app with no support from a company that's gone. Of course filling a bug report would have solved my problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is not a `call`, but a `jmp`, and you want a direct `jmp`. Direct jumps usually use an addressing relative to the next instruction's address (see [my answer to SO question: How encode a relative short jmp in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889643/how-encode-a-relative-short-jmp-in-x86/14893159#14893159)).  Relative to the *end* of the jump instruction is another way to look at it.

So, you are at `0x1000027a9` and want to jump to `0x100003b6e`.

`0x100003b6e` - `0x1000027a9` = `0x000013C5` = `5061d`, so that definitively doesn't fit in a short jump (`rel8` in Intel documentation), but you need `jmp rel32`. It would fit in `rel16` too, but that's not supported in x86-64 (in 64-bit mode).

So, you want a `jmp rel32`. This is encoded **relative to the next instruction after `jmp`**, and as the length of the instruction is 5 bytes (`E9 xx xx xx xx`), `rel32` will be `0x000013C0`. As x86 is a little-endian architecture, it is encoded as `E9 C0 13 00 00`.

To confirm this, I assembled a small test executable with NASM and disassembled it with ndisasm (note I left first `0x10000000` bytes out, but as the jump is relative, it doesn't change anything in the encoding):

```
000027A8  90                nop
000027A9  E9C0130000        jmp dword 0x3b6e ; this is the instruction you need.
000027AE  90                nop
```

Comment: WORKS!! THANK YOU SO MUCH! Where can I learn more about x86 assembly? I found some material online, but it's rather incomplete or very old.

Comment: I find Introduction to 64 Bit Intel Assembly Language Programming for Linux quite useful. As OS/X and Linux use the same System V ABI and function calls, I think it should work for OS/X too almost completely. There are more materials for 32-bit code, but as you have a 64-bit system, I really recommend to learn straight x86-64, it's much more convenient (more and bigger registers that make your life as a programmer a lot more comfortable). [Programming from the Ground Up Book](http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/pgubook/) may also be useful, even though I dislike AT&T syntax.

Comment: Great! Done the same way for the 32bit code and it worked like a charm. Looks like I initially forgot the architecture was little-endian...

Comment: Terminology: relative to next instruction's *address* might be better.  RIP during execution of an instruction points to the end of that instruction, for the purposes of RIP-relative addressing modes like `[RIP + 0]`.  So if you think about it this way, the "next instruction's `rip`" would be the end of the next instruction, not the end of the branch.