# x86 JMP opcode structure

Tags: c, assembly, x86, intel

I'm just looking at the .text section of a simple exe I wrote in C, and I'm just trying to work out how some x86 opcodes are structured.

From what I've been reading, it seems that 0xe9 is a single byte opcode for a relative jump (JMP), however I'm unsure how the rest of the bytes actually form the jump address.

I'm using the super online disassembler [ODA](http://www.onlinedisassembler.com/) to disassemble my program, and this is what is displayed:

```
.text:0x00411005    e936210000  jmp    0x00413140
```

So 0xe9 is the JMP instruction, and as this is a 32-bit executable, I'm assuming the next four bytes are going to be the address for the jump, however I'm a little unsure as to how they are actually structured.

If anyone could help shine some light on his, I'd appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Isn't this an almost verbatim copy-paste of the question you just deleted? The same advice (read the manual) applies to this question.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14921735/asm-write-a-jump-command-to-a-x86-64-binary-file/14922390#14922390

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a relative jump, meaning that the destination is given as relative to the next instruction.

This instruction is at address 0x411005 and takes 5 bytes, so the next instruction is at address 0x41100a. The relative amount to jump (encoded as little-endian, i.e. the bytes are stored from least significant to most significant) is 0x2136. So the destination of the jump is 0x41100a + 0x2136 = 0x413140.

Comment: Where could I find the part you said about little endian? (I believe and confirmed it myself right after having read this, but I needed to know about JNZ, which I found and I'm following the little endian again, but I'd like to know where you read that so I could know about the other instructions)

Comment: @DADi590 All instructions and their encodings are described in the [Intel architecture manual](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-sdm.html) volume 2.