# x86 / x64 Using a relative jump to return from a subroutine

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I'm needing to write a bit of assembly that I will be writing into the address space of another process (already running.)

Essentially what I am wanting to do is every time this assembly is invoked, it will compare a value from the stack to a predefined value and then if it matches the pre defined value I want to call a function whose pointer will be hard coded into the assembly and if not, I want the assembly to essentially do nothing, so return.

So far I have the following (just going to post the snippet for x86 to keep things simple)

```
mov eax, [esp+0x04] ; this is the value from the stack
cmp eax, 0x01 ; this is the predefined value I am comparing to
```

As stated above, if the value in eax matches the 0x01 in this case, I want it to jump to a function (predefined pointer so can hardcode into the assembly,) else I want the sub routine to return. The problem is I don't know how to do this without the use of a label, which I don't believe I will be able to use as this is going to be executed in the context of another process and so the addresses will not start at 0 (for the assembly I will be calling.)

I've heard that you can do a relative jump but I was having trouble implementing something along those lines.

Could somebody show me how I could achieve this using a relative jump or another method?

Comment: basically a duplicate of [Write a jump command to a x86-64 binary file](//stackoverflow.com/q/14921735) which shows how a relative jump is encoded.  You need to know the source *and* target address, or at least the relative displacement.  Knowing the absolute target alone is not useful (or you'd have to use a less efficient jump over a `mov eax, imm32`/`jmp eax`)

Comment: How do you determine the address you want to jump to? If you know the address, you can load it into eax and do “jmp eax”.

Comment: @prl: seems inefficient.  You're injecting this into an already-running process, so you definitely have the source and target addresses available while you're copying this in.  e.g. use `db 0x0f, 0x84` ; `branch_offset: dd 0` to encode a [`jz rel32`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc) with a label on the relative displacement, and update the displacement when you inject it.  ([How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/47494744) shows more about manually encoding relative branches).

Answer (score 1):

You're injecting this into an already-running process, so you definitely have the source and target addresses available while you're copying this in.

x86 conditional branches are available with a 32-bit `rel32` displacement, relative to the *end* of the branch instruction.  i.e. if the branch condition is true, they do `RIP += rel32` after the usual setting RIP = end of this instruction.

**`jz rel32` is a good way to make a conditional tailcall to another function, or fall through to a `ret` instruction.**

See https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/jcc for the opcodes.  [How does $ work in NASM, exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47494744/how-does-work-in-nasm-exactly) has an example of manually encoding a `call rel32`, and the resulting machine code.

Also [Write a jump command to a x86-64 binary file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14921735) for another Q&A about branch encoding.

```
    mov   eax, [esp+0x04]
    cmp   eax, 1

    db 0x0f, 0x84      ; opcode for je rel32
branch_offset: dd 0    ; the rel32 itself

    ; fall-through path
    ret
```

After you assemble this into machine code, you should write code to modify that dword (aka `int32_t`) 0 once you know the source and target addresses in the target process.  The `0` is just a placeholder.

(`je +0` will just go to the next instruction whether ZF is set or not.)

**Or if you know the source and target addresses, you can get YASM to do the math for you at assemble time:**

```
    bits 64
    org  0x12345             ; this block of code will start at this address

    cmp  dword [rsp+4], 1
    je   0x123456
    ret
```

Assembling this into a flat binary gives us:

```
$ yasm -f bin -l /dev/stdout jz.asm
     1                                 %line 1+1 jz.asm
     2                                 [bits 64]
     3                                 [org 0x12345]
     4                                 
     5 00000000 837C240401              cmp dword [rsp+4], 1
     6 00000005 0F84FD101100            je 0x123456
     7 0000000B C3                      ret
     8                                 
     9 0000000C B854230100              mov eax, $
```

**The `ORG` directive doesn't seem to work with NASM, only YASM.**  I don't know why.

The `mov` instruction is there to see what address the assembler thinks its assembling at.  With NASM we get `B8[0C000000]` instead of the expected `54 23 01 00` as the immediate of the `mov` instruction (its own address).

---

If you know the relative displacement ahead of time / as an assemble-time constant (but not either absolute address), that's fine, too.

**In NASM syntax, `je  +0x555555` assembles to `0F 84 55 55 55 00`**.

But not in YASM: in YASM `+0x555555` is just the absolute address `0x555555` as a branch target.

---

**Related:**

- [How to write an absolute target for a near direct relative call/jmp in MASM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50058523/how-to-write-an-absolute-target-for-a-near-direct-relative-call-jmp-in-masm) (TL:DR you can't)
- [Call an absolute pointer in x86 machine code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19552158/call-an-absolute-pointer-in-x86-machine-code) - shows how to encode relative branches, and workarounds moving an address into a register and using `jmp reg` if you can't make a `jcc rel32` work.