# instruction pointer in near jump 8086

Tags: assembly, conditional-statements, x86, emu8086

how the result of IP=5 is reached ?
shouldn't we add `IP(new)=IP(current)+disp = 002+ 002=04`

or does the new IP is calculated after the jump instructions end (start of next ) `IP(new)=IP(next instruction) +disp = 03+02=05`

***Image taken from THE INTEL MICROPROCESSORS Eighth Edition BARRY B. BREY***
[image: Image taken from THE INTEL MICROPROCESSORS Eighth Edition BARRY B. BREY]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How encode a relative short jmp in x86](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889643/how-encode-a-relative-short-jmp-in-x86)

Comment: `IP = 0002H` is wrong in that image.  While execution that 3-byte near jump instruction starting at `1000:0000`,  IP = 0003 not 2.  A short jump would only be 2 bytes long, not including the `00` byte.  (The difference is the opcode, which isn't shown numerically here.)

Comment: @teapot418: Not an exact duplicate: a short jump is 2 bytes long. This is a non-short near jump, 3 bytes long. That distinction is key to the error in the text next to the diagram in this book, so that duplicate isn't ideal.

Comment: @PeterCordes at least the linked answer does mention "relative to the next instruction" which I understood as the main point of this question